# Value of NSLayoutConstraint constant always return 0 swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I m doing an iOS project using Swift 3, I have a UIPagerViewController and I create a button in the border of one of the ViewControllers inside it. After that I added a constraint to the button like you can see in this image below :
[image]

The constraint have a value of **-33**

After that I create the associated IBOutlet to this constraint :

```
@IBOutlet weak var rightButtonConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I want to get this value programmatically when the ViewController start so I did :

```
public var defaultRightConstraint: CGFloat = 0.0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            defaultRightConstraint = rightButtonConstraint.constant // the constraint return 0
            print(" DEFAULT RIGHT CONSTRAINT \(defaultRightConstraint)") // Returns 0 and not -33 why ?
        }
```

but the value I got is already 0 and not -33 what I m doing wrong ?

Edit :

I tried that without success :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        defaultRightConstraint = rightButtonConstraint.constant
        print(" DEFAULT RIGHT CONSTRAINT \(rightButtonConstraint.constant)")
    }
```

Comment: Maybe in the `viewDidLoad`, the view isn't yet layout. Maybe you should try it in the `layoutSubviews()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, it depends what you want to do.

Comment: @Zico I added in the question what I tried but it's not working

Comment: @frando what is the value that you get? I'm not sure that you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` as the view just has been "layout".

Comment: @Zico I already get 0.0 it's crazy

Comment: @Zico does the PagerViewController influence the value ?

Comment: I don't think so if it is above in the view hierarchy. I just tried the same thing and I got `-33.0` inside the `viewDidLoad`. Are you sure you bind the right constraint ?

Comment: @Zico yes I tried too, it works on a simple view controller, I tried to reassign it in my projet it always return 0, I forgot to say that my Viewcontrollers are in a Container View maybe it's this component that create the problem ?

Comment: @Zico THE Pager is embed in the container view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad()`, the view's subviews is not layout yet. Try to put your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, or, before you check the constraint's constant, call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: I added in the question what I tried but it's not working

Comment: @fandro Can you provide more details about your view controller's context? I created a project with a root `UIPageViewController`, and set some view controllers as pages. And... I can always get correct constraint constant in `viewDidLoad()` and no need to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: @fandro Here is my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6q3r1rqqtws6vbg/LayoutTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for your help like I said, my view controllers are in a Container View maybe this create the problem ? THE Pager is embed in the container view

Comment: @fandro well, I tried, and it still works... have you try to re-link the IBOutlet?

Comment: can you send me the project by dropbox, to compare with mine please ?

Comment: @fandro Here it is~ https://www.dropbox.com/s/lslv3wcixjzqj6k/LayoutTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Your example is the same as me, I will continue to investigate and I will tell you why when I found it thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know where but I have a mistake in my project, I did a lot of test in yours everything works pertly thanks for your help !!